# Shiny Leaflet not being able to pick user uploaded shapefile(sf_object) data path

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf

I am creating a shiny app that:

1. Allows the user to upload a shapefile (sf_object) "filemap" (`I am assuming sf wants all the files associated with a shapefile exported from ArcPro`).
2. Based on the uploaded shapefile, the user will then be able to
   select a column/variable of interest to map (mapview).

I am getting this error while the app is loaded:

```
Error in pointData.default: Don't know how to get path data from object of class character
```

How can I fix this error?

Sample data (`part of the data from the shapefile to be uploaded`):

```
structure(list(Info = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), tmean = c(22.2395992279053, 22.7657985687256, 
24.4260005950928, 19.601001739502, 17.5659999847412), CITYNAME = c("NORTH LAUDERDALE", 
"NORTH LAUDERDALE", "NORTH LAUDERDALE", "NORTH LAUDERDALE", "NORTH LAUDERDALE"
), Model = c("PRISM", "PRISM", "PRISM", "PRISM", "PRISM"), Variable = c("tmean", 
"tmean", "tmean", "tmean", "tmean"), Datatype = c("provisional", 
"provisional", "stable", "stable", "stable"), Resolution = c("4kmM3", 
"4kmM3", "4kmM3", "4kmM3", "4kmM3"), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L), month = c(11L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 2L), TMin = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), TMax = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.2083333333333
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
    26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
    26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
    26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -80.2083333327448, 
ymin = 26.2083333333333, xmax = -80.2083333327448, ymax = 26.2083333333333
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Info = NA_integer_, 
tmean = NA_integer_, CITYNAME = NA_integer_, Model = NA_integer_, 
Variable = NA_integer_, Datatype = NA_integer_, Resolution = NA_integer_, 
year = NA_integer_, month = NA_integer_, TMin = NA_integer_, 
TMax = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(png)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)


    # Define UI for application that draws an interactive ggplot
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
    ui =   navbarPage("Temperature Analysis", theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                    tabPanel("Temperature",
                    icon = icon("chart-area"),
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("filemap", label = "Input Shapefile 
                                                         (.shp,.dbf,.sbn,.sbx,.shx,.prj)",
                                                         multiple=TRUE,
                                                         accept = c(".shp",
                                                                    ".dbf",
                                                                    ".sbn",
                                                                    ".sbx",
                                                                    ".shx",
                                                                    ".prj",
                                                                    ".cpg",
                                                                    ".xml"))),
                    mainPanel(selectInput(inputId = "Temp", label = "Select Temperature Variable", choices = c("Mean Temperature" = "TMean", "Minimum Temperature" = "TMin", "Maximum Temperature" = "TMax")),
                              leafletOutput("mapview")))))
```

Server

```
# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
    server = function(input, output, session) {
            
            # Read-in shapefile function
        Read_Shapefile = function(shp_path) {
          infiles = shp_path$datapath # get the location of files
          dir = unique(dirname(infiles)) # get the directory
          outfiles = file.path(dir, shp_path$name) # create new path name
          name = strsplit(shp_path$name[1], "\\.")[[1]][1] # strip name 
          purrr::walk2(infiles, outfiles, ~file.rename(.x, .y)) # rename files
          x = read_sf(file.path(dir, paste0(name, ".shp"))) # read-in shapefile
          return(x)
        }
        
        # Read-shapefile once user submits files
        
          observe({
            req(input$filemap)
            Temp_map =  Read_Shapefile(input$filemap)
                
           pal_fun = colorQuantile("YlOrRd", NULL, n = 5) # Define color palette and classes
          
          t_popup = paste0("Air Temperature", input$Temp) # Popup depends on the "Temp" variable selected 
          
          output$mapview =  renderLeaflet({leaflet(input$Temp) %>% # Map depends on the "Temp" variable selected
          addCircleMarkers(
          fillColor = ~pal_fun(input$Temp), # set fill color with function from above and value
          fillOpacity = 0.8, # make it nicer
          popup = t_popup)
          })
          
          })
        
        
    
}
```

Upon selecting a variable to map, I get further warnings/errors:

[image]

```
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/0.cpg' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.cpg', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/1.dbf' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.dbf', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/2.prj' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.prj', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/3.sbn' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.sbn', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/4.sbx' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.sbx', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/5.shp' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.shp', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/6.xml' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.shp.xml', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning in file.rename(.x, .y) :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/7.shx' to 'C:/Users/ed/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWWEmJR/48579773928f2819571ef8e5/BCU_Temp_1980_2021.shx', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Warning: Error in pointData.default: Don't know how to get location data from object of class character
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried changing the code a bit and now the error is gone but I am not getting the `leaflet` output.

[image]

Posting only the changed code:

```
# Read-shapefile once user submits files
Temp_map =   reactive({
        req(input$filemap)
         Read_Shapefile(input$filemap)
      
      pal_fun = colorQuantile("YlOrRd", NULL, n = 5) # Define color palette and classes
      
      observe({
        data = Temp_map
        updateSearchInput(session, "Temp", choices = names(data))
      })
      
      t_popup = paste0("Air Temperature", input$Temp) # Popup depends on the "Temp" variable selected 
      
      output$mapview =  renderLeaflet({leaflet(input$Temp) %>% # Map depends on the "Temp" variable selected
        addCircleMarkers(data = input$Temp,
          fillColor = ~pal_fun(input$Temp), # set fill color with function from above and value
          fillOpacity = 0.8, # make it nicer
          popup = t_popup)  # add popup
      })
      
      })
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have further modified the code. Now the `select input menu` is able to pick up the `columns` from the shapefile. However, leaflet is still returning the same error.

```
Error in pointData.default: Don't know how to get path data from object of class character
```

Part of code that I changed:

```
# Read-shapefile once user submits files
        
        Temp_map =   reactive({
            req(input$filemap)
          df = Read_Shapefile(input$filemap)
          df
        })
          # # Code for allowing the user to select the variables/columns of interest to map
          # info = eventReactive(input$Temp, {
          #   req(Temp_map())
          #   t = Temp_map()
          #   t
          # })
         
          # observe({
          #   req(input$Temp) 
          #   updateSelectInput(session,"Temp", "Please select the temperature variable to map:", choices = names(Temp_map))
          # }) # Allows the user to select the column/variable to map based on uploaded shapefile (Temp_map)
          
          pal_fun = colorQuantile("YlOrRd", NULL, n = 5) # Define color palette and classes
          
          observe({
            dff = Temp_map()
            updateSelectInput(session, "Temp", choices = names(dff))
          })
          
          #t_popup = paste0("Air Temperature", input$Temp) # Popup depends on the "Temp" variable selected 
          
          output$mapview =  renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>% # Map depends on the "Temp" variable selected
            addCircleMarkers(data = input$Temp,
              fillColor = ~pal_fun(input$Temp), # set fill color with function from above and value
              fillOpacity = 0.8, # make it nicer
              popup = TRUE)  # add popup
          })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be supplying Temp_map() as your data for leaflet or mapview to produce the map and then supply input$temp as the variable for your colours?

Comment: You mean this? `output$mapview =  renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>% # Map depends on the "Temp" variable selected
            addCircleMarkers(data = Temp_map,
              fillColor = ~pal_fun(input$Temp), # set fill color with function from above and value
              fillOpacity = 0.8, # make it nicer
              popup = TRUE)  # add popup
          })` If so then this returns the same error as well. `Don't know how to get location data from object of class reactiveExpr,reactive,function`

Comment: Yes, but where temp map is a reactive function I think you need the brackets as well, so data =Temp_map().

Comment: I find mapview a bit easier to work with so I would write it as: ```output$mapview =  renderLeaflet({
  MAP_DATA <- Temp_map()
  MAPVIEW_MAP <- mapview(MAP_DATA, zcol=input$Temp)
  MAPVIEW_MAP@map
})
```

Comment: this works thank you however the map is I think is only showing `a single value (last value to be precise)` on the map, however the shapefile consists of `40 years  (year column )of monthly (month column) data.` What could be the issue? Did you try the code on your end?

Comment: I'm not sure, the data example you provided has 5 points but they are all in the same location so drawing on top of each other

Comment: alright thank you I guess I will post a new question.

Comment: I found the problem `mapview` is not `averaging` values of points that have the same value. It's rather mapping them on top of each other. I don't if this is possible with `mapview or not`.

Comment: I would not expect it to.  You might want to look into clustering, though I don't think mapview has that functionality whcih woudl mean going back to leaflet, or tmap in view mode,  ex: ```leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
    color = ~ viridis(nlevels(as.factor(data$tmean))),
    popup = ~ (paste0(
      "Year: ", data$year, "<br>" , "Temp: ", data$tmean
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Could you please post your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72663266/r-shiny-leaflet-mapview-only-showing-the-last-value-on-the-choropleth-map)? Thank you for your time